# Limit .droppable() to only one item?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list of multiple colors, orange, blue, green. There are only two `.droppable()` places, in my real application this is team A vs team B, in my fiddle example I use colors. You can see here **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3X5jW/2/)**.

I am not sure how to approach writing it so that only ONE color is allowed in each box (the current color that is already inside gets sent back to the menu list and the new draggable item becomes the current one)

I am sure with constant fiddling and googling I could figure it out, but hopefully someone has experienced this, it seems it would be quite commmon (cant find anything ATM on this).

Here is a snippet of the Jquery and HTML

jQuery:

```
$('#menu li').draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    containment: "document"
});

$('.left .show, .right .show').droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.detach();
        $(this).addClass(ui.draggable.attr('data-team'))
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="jsFiddle">
    <div id="open-menu">< Open Menu</div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li data-team="orange">orange</li>
            <li data-team="blue">blue</li>
            <li data-team="green">green</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="display">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="show"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="show"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Again a fiddle that should explain all, open the menu (I know some z-index issues with the draggable element will tweak that out) drag one color into each box, then you are left with only one color. With that remaining color you should be able to drag it into either box and whatever color in that box is sent back to the menu.

I am not sure if there is a `reattach` function but essentially I need to reattach the color that is being overridden back to the menu, then detach the new color.

It seems simple enough I may figure it out, but this might be a nice little brush up for some of you.

**My Updated Fiddle** *Still needs tweaks*: I fiddled and fiddled some more here is what I came up with http://jsfiddle.net/3X5jW/5/

I still want to see answers and reward the best answer, maybe there is a much more simple solution than mine.

Comment: After reading your question again I see that you want them to be replaced.

Comment: I came up with a fiddle, it works. Let me know what you guys think about using each and just hiding instead of detaching. http://jsfiddle.net/3X5jW/5/ Still needs a few tweaks.

Comment: It works somewhat but when you drag two colors over it still shows two draggable colors in the list.

Comment: Yeah just noticed that... I could some conditionals, I like yours, its nice I am playing around with both. Maybe a mix of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.left .show, .right .show').droppable({
  drop: function (event, ui) {
    if($(this).data('color') != undefined){
        $(this).removeClass($(this).data('color'));
        $('#menu ul').append('<li data-team="'+$(this).data('color')+'">'+$(this).data('color')+'</li>');
        $('#menu li').draggable({
            helper: "clone",
            containment: "document"
        });
    }
    ui.draggable.detach();
    $(this).addClass(ui.draggable.attr('data-team'));
    $(this).data('color',ui.draggable.attr('data-team'));
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3X5jW/6/

Comment: Thanks for this, give me a minuet to play around with this and fully 100% understand what is going on, will give a check in a second.